# How to wait ajax done then retrigger ajax in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to rxjs and I wanna do a simple feature, make a button every click event will send a ajax, when prev ajax does not respond the button just return

In pure js, I just set a flag to check ajax done or not, but I know how to do this feature in rxjs.

pure js code like

```
let flag = false;
let el = document.querySelector("#btn");
el.addEventListener("click",handleBtn);
let handleBtn = () => {
   if(flag) return;  // if ajax no response then return
   fakeAjaxCall().then(
     val => flag = true, 
     reason => console.log(reason)
   )
}
```

maybe in rxjs like this,

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from "rxjs/Rx";
    const btn$ = Observable.fromEvent(
      this.refs["btn"],
      "click"
    ).subscribe(fakeAjaxCall());
```

Comment: `switchMap` operator is your guy - read this for more details https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/

Comment: thank you and I read that article, but I found `switchMap` is not my guy, because I do not wanna request again when ajax does not respond, so how to pause the initial source observable?

Comment: So, if I understand right this time, you want to click a button, send an ajax request and ignore all possible other clicks on that button until the ajax returns. If this is the case, the `exaustMap` may be your guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html).
So, for your exmaple it is:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from "rxjs/Rx";
    const btn$ = Observable.fromEvent(
      this.refs["btn"],
      "click"
    ).pipe(exhaustMap(() => fakeAjaxCall())
    .subscribe();
```

It will ignore all emits from `button$` until observable from `exhaustMap` will not be completed